# Removing Element from jquery object as populating DOM

Tags: jquery

I want to parse javascript object as html. Without appending it to dom. 
But my code is not working

```
var html ='<div><div class="b"><div class="a">hello</div><div class"c">bye</div></div></div>';
var j=$(html);
var k=$(j).not('.a');
alert($(k).html());
```

I want to hide div having class a . but code is not working. Where my code is wrong ?
demo
http://jsfiddle.net/fAtZz/2/

Comment: First thoughts: `$(j).find('.a').hide();` But how are you assessing whether an element that's not in the DOM is being hidden (or shown) at all?

Comment: @David Thomas element is not in dom. I want to parse javascript object. I am getting element from ajax request request. I don't want to put full content in dom.

Comment: My question was: 'how do you define "hidden," given that the `html` string isn't in the DOM, and, therefore, not shown anyway?'

Comment: @David Thomas I am getting object from ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fAtZz/4/

The idea is to create a proper `div` wrapper around your html and append this html to this div. After that you can access to inner elements and modify them. However I'm not sure that it is what you want :)

Comment: so we will need to create a dom element to populate it using jquery ?

Comment: i think that we can't manipulate with object represented with the text, but we can do anything when it is a proper HTML element

Comment: btw, this works: http://jsfiddle.net/fAtZz/5/ It seems you had the problems with the selector

Comment: @Igor Dymno: why do you need an extra div? the structure already is wrapped in a div.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for,

```
var html_content = '<div><div class="b"><div class="a">hello</div><div class="c">bye</div></div></div>';
var i = $(html_content);

i.find('.a').remove();

alert(i.html());
```

we look for elements with the class `a` and remove it from the node stored in `i`.

Comment: yes. that is correct answer. but first person had already replied, and I can accept only one answer.